# Multiple Spring OAuth2 Authentication and Authorization

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am developing an application which consists of two users' category, and they require two different authentication endpoints. I saw couple of tutorials on how to use Spring Security OAuth2. But I wish to extend the authorization server classes and resource server classes, so that I can have the two authentication endpoints for my app. Any assistance will be highly welcome. Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'd like two different mappings to point to the same authorization server. For example: "/oauth/token" and "provider/oauth/token"